# Using jQuery Infinite scroll plugin without pagination markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

So I'm trying to implement the popular inifnite scroll plugin to replace my current home made infinite scroll script:

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/
&
https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Anyway it seems like this plugin requires there to be html pagination on the page. Namely due to these options:

```
nextSelector: "div.navigation a:first",
navSelector: "div.navigation",
```

I don't have pagination markup on the page. I don't care if my site isn't compatible for crawlers/js disabled users.

So is there a way to implement this plugin without a physical html pagination?

In my custom script I was doing something like:

```
var $page = 1;

// Load content for $page

$page++;
```

Anything like this, i.e. I can pass in the starting page as an integer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this, very simplified version of infinite scroll, that doesn't require any pagination elements.

http://www.innovativephp.com/demo/infinitescroll/

Answer (score 1):

You can create it easily with jQuery/javascript.

It's a bit hard to write a universal for anything now, but the main principle is this:

If you're loading latest content (newest first, older scrolled):

1. Load first set of elements (weather it be blogsposts, images, quotes) that takes a bit more than screen height. Keep the last item's ID in a variable.
2. use setInterval to detect if user scrolled the page, then load data that has lower ID than your last ID that you saved. Then keep saving last ID's and load new content.

Good luck!

Something like this:

```
function loadnewdata()
{
    // do ajax stuff, update data.
}
setInterval(
  function (){
    if(($(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(document).scrollTop()) < 500){
    loadnewdata();
    }
  }, 
  500
);
```

You'd write the loadNewData() function for yourself, of course. Depends on your data.
This loads new data each 500 if the user has scrolled the page.

Comment: I know I can make it myself, I already did. But I want to replace it with that plugin because it has a lot of other features as well as jquery masonry integration which is tricky otherwise.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I could help, haven't even been able to get that script working before.